# How to debug the main SafariPlugIn project?

Tags: cocoa, safari

Ok, Now I want to add a menu in the safari menubar. I Create a Cocoa bundle project in Xcode .and then change the target extension is "webplugin" .and then add WebPluginMIMETypesFilename
com.example.webplugin.plist
to the info.plist.but I don't know the  is right?. I make the prinpical class is my main plugin class SafariPlug . and then In the safariPlug.m I implement the methods:

// This method returns an NSView object that conforms to the WebPlugIn informal protocol.

- (NSView *)plugInViewWithArguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments

{

```
return [[[self alloc] initWithArguments:arguments] autorelease];
```

}

- (id)initWithArguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments

{

self = [super init];

```
if (self) 
    [MenuController sharedController];  // trigger the menu items to be added

return self;
```

}

at the end I followed the url:[run safari to debug plunIn project](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2006/qa1500.html)

add a debug bundle:myProject.webplugin into the folder:/library/internet plug-ins/
But when I make a breakpoint into the

- (NSView *)plugInViewWithArguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments

the program didn't load in the debug mode? SomeOne which have experience can tell me the step of add a menu into the safari? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari will not load your plugin unless you load a webpage that references your plugin. So I'm afraid the plugin type you're working on is not officially supported, by the current plugin API of safari.

You can use [SIBML](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) to write this kind of plugin. But SIMBL is not something officially supported by Apple, and a lot of people consider it a hack.

Comment: Now I want to make a safari plugin with simbl , and I have read the Armchair Guide To Cocoa Reverse Engineering. but when implement the method - (void)load; how to use the plugin to get the safari DOM object ,just like PIC or Flash URL ? Thank you very much !